# NetMiko - LAB SSH io.TextIOWrapper - Object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Tags: python

I've been trying to tweak a script in my lab for days, and nothing works.
If I run the command only with: 'show vlan' => The script understands, and returns me
But if I run a list with a series of commands, it reports the io_Text error

I've already tried to create a variable (cat), and it reports a timeout error, but in the variable that reads the list (commands), it reports the rstrip error.

## Any suggestion?

```py
#print(device_list)
comandos = open("cli.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
print(type(comandos))
with open("cli.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as c:
    gato = c.read()
    print(type(gato))
    print(gato)
print(type(gato))
print(gato)

config_comands = ['show vlan','show int status']
print(type(config_comands))

config_comands_1 = 'show vlan'
print(type(config_comands_1))
'''config_commands = 'show vlan'
print(type(config_commands))'''

for each_device in device_list:
    connection = ConnectHandler(**each_device)
    connection.enable()
    print(f'Connecting to {each_device["host"]}')
    output = connection.send_command(comandos,expect_string=r'#')
    print(output)
```

Outputs:

```
============================================================
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Users\jardel.almeida\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\getpass.py", line 100
    return fallback_getpass(prompt, stream)
GetPassWarning: Can not control echo on the terminal.
Warning: Password input may be echoed.
Please enter the password:
<class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
<class 'str'>
terminal length 0
show run
show ip int brief
show clock
show interface status | inc connected
show vlan

<class 'str'>
terminal length 0
show run
show ip int brief
show clock
show interface status | inc connected
show vlan

<class 'list'>
<class 'str'>
Connecting to 172.16.1.50

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jardel.almeida/OneDrive - NTT/Desktop/AUTOMACAO_EDISEN/NOVO/internet_testes 29 Ok + com Tupla_String_Conversão.py", line 44, in <module>
    output = connection.send_command(comandos,expect_string=r'#')
  File "C:\Users\jardel.almeida\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\netmiko\utilities.py", line 596, in wrapper_decorator
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\jardel.almeida\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1635, in send_command
    command_string = self.normalize_cmd(command_string)
  File "C:\Users\jardel.almeida\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1852, in normalize_cmd
    command = command.rstrip()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'rstrip'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that connection.send_command(…, expect_string=r'#')` is expecting a string of commands, and you're providing it with a file-object.

If your `cli.txt` file is a file containing commands you want to pass into the `.send_command` method, then I believe this *might* work:

```py
connection.send_command(gato, expect_string=r'#')
```

If the commands you want to send are stored in the list `config_commands` then try this:

```py
...

config_comands = ['show vlan','show int status']

for each_device in device_list:
    connection = ConnectHandler(**each_device)
    connection.enable()
    print(f'Connecting to {each_device["host"]}')
    
    for command in config_commands:
        output = connection.send_command(command, expect_string=r'#')
```

---

If you would like to run each of the commands that are in the file 'cli.txt', try using the following code:

```py
with open("cli.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as c:
    commands = c.readlines()

for each_device in device_list:
    connection = ConnectHandler(**each_device)
    connection.enable()
    print(f'Connecting to {each_device["host"]}')
    
    for cmd in commands:
        output = connection.send_command(cmd ,expect_string=r'#')
        print(each_device, output)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Identifying the for in the second option worked perfectly. But in this case I am adding the commands in the no. I want to get them from a list, I even tried the first option and it keeps reporting the error

-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 1852, in normalize_cmd
    command = command.rstrip()
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

-packages\netmiko\base_connection.py", line 651, in read_until_pattern
    raise ReadTimeout(msg)
netmiko.exceptions.ReadTimeout:

Comment: Pattern not detected: 'terminal\\ length\\ 0\\\nshow\\ run\\\nshow\\ ip\\ int\\ brief\\\nshow\\ clock\\\nshow\\ interface\\ status\ \ \\|\\ inc\\ connected\\\nshow\\ vlan' in output.

Things you might try to fix this:
1. Adjust the regex pattern to better identify the terminating string. Note, in
many situations the pattern is automatically based on the network device's prompt.

Comment: In your cli.txt file, is each command you want to run on a separate line of the file? Can you edit in the contents of `cli.txt` into the body of your question?

Comment: Sure! He follows:


terminal length 0
show run
show ip int brief
show clock
show interface status | inc connected
show vlan

But each command on a line

Comment: <class '_io.TextIOWrapper'>
!
terminal length 0
show run
show ip int brief
show clock
show interface status | inc connected
show vlan
!
Connecting to 172.16.1.50

Traceback (most recent call last):
 
    output = connection.send_command(comandos,expect_string=r'#')
  File "C:\Users\jardel.almeida\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\netmiko\utilities.py", line 596, in wrapper_decorator
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'rstrip'

Comment: Try using that final code snippet to run each command from the file 'cli.txt' on each of your devices.

Comment: I'm trying, but I think I'll study some more.

Comment: Hi, I was missing something, but it worked after your tips.
Thanks!

commands = open("cli2.txt")
cmd = commands.readlines()

for each_device in device_list:
     connection = ConnectHandler(**each_device)
     connection.enable()

     for command in cmd:
         command = command.rstrip('\n')